# After a clean installation Ubuntu does not see the hdmi port

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, hdmi

Acer Nitro 5 i5-8300H GeForce 1050. 
Installed Ubuntu 20.04 and stopped working monitor via hdmi(before it was 19.10 and everything worked). `xrandr` does not output only the laptop display, there are no lines with the mention of hdmi. Tried switching to `lightdm` didn't help. Reinstalling the system several times also failed. Switching drivers didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. What worked for me was to downgrade the NVIDIA driver to version 390.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the NVIDIA Server. If it is empty, this implies your video graphics card (NVIDIA) is not being loaded. if so, reboot your system and while booting stop at the grub system and press <kbd>e</kbd> to change to edit mode.

You should see some line that starts with `Linux`. In that line, if `nomodeset` is written, remove it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to save and now after booting up, try connecting the monitor. It should work like a charm.